# Why diff-in-diff over regression with control variable for measuring treatment intervention in time series?

Tags: regression, time-series, inference, difference-in-difference, causalimpact

Let's suppose we have a time series data set, with an intervention period for the treatment where the mean of the independent variable increases by 10. The goal is to measure the effect of the treatment, and return the average daily (or whatever time unit) effect size in the post period.

Simulated in R.

```
set.seed(1)
x1 <- 100 + arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.999), n = 100)
y <- 1.2 * x1 + rnorm(100)
y[71:100] <- y[71:100] + 10
data <- cbind(y, x1)
```

Additionally, let's assume covariate `x1` is highly correlated in the pre-period and not given the treatment. Why can't we just regress our $y$ on a dummy variable for pre/post + covariate `x1`? If `x1` is highly correlated shouldn't it produce unbiased estimates of the conditional means for pre and post-period?

I have read that autocorrelation is an issue when using ordinary least squares (OLS) regression on time series and it increases the false positive rate, even with a highly correlated covariate. How can I generate simulated data to prove that it increases that false positive rate?

How does a difference-in-difference (DiD) model fix this issue? I'm using google's [CausalImpact](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CausalImpact/CausalImpact.pdf), but I think the idea is the same.

EDIT: Clarifying covariate x1

Comment: Welcome to CV. Difference-in-differences could work if you acquire a control group. Do you observe a unit(s) that do not receive the treatment?

Comment: Covariate x1 does not receive the treatment.

Comment: Causal Impact and DID are not the same.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov I agree. I'm trying to understand why estimating the causal effect of the treatment, indicated by pre/post, using the regression equation (y ~ dummy pre/post + covariate x1) produces bad estimates.